# Dolphin has no icons on Pop!_OS 19.10

Tags: gnome, kde, dolphin

I installed KDE's `dolphin` on Debian/Gnome-based Pop!_OS. Now, I know installing KDE apps on Gnome will not always be painless, but in the past I've always been able to get Dolphin to work flawlessly on Ubuntu by installing additional packages (`oxygen-icon-theme` and `libqt5libqgtk2`), and I am hoping to get to that state on Pop!_OS as well. Unfortunately, currently all icons are missing:

[image]

Starting the app from the terminal, there is a lot of messages hinting at missing icons:

```
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/ui/"
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
Gtk-Message: 16:12:32.587: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

As an aside, I tried installing `dolphin` with `flatpak`, but that is firstly huge, and secondly has other issues (handling doubleclicks; with flatpak not being aware of which other apps are installed). So I'd prefer to solve it with the version I get with `sudo apt install dolphin`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with : 
*sudo apt install qt5ct*.
Then run *qt5ct* and set icons to KDE set. Then reboot. 
Worked for Me Good luck.

Comment: That's great, and working, many thanks!